# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'symbol'. dosent exist

Tags: python

I get this when running:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 5, in <module>
    import Quartz
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Quartz/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import AppKit
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/AppKit/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import Foundation
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Foundation/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import CoreFoundation
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/CoreFoundation/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import objc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ._bridgesupport import *  # noqa: F401, F403, E402
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/_bridgesupport.py", line 15, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 29, in <module>
    import symbol
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'symbol'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/williamgiles/Desktop/wart/client/wart.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 544, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_osx as platformModule
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 7, in <module>
    assert False, "You must first install pyobjc-core and pyobjc: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html"
AssertionError: You must first install pyobjc-core and pyobjc: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
```

It just started like an hour ago after changing nothing. I am very confused.

I have tried `pip3 install symbol` and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error likely means that you don't have the module symbol installed. I understand that pip3 install symbol doesn't work, but given the other exceptions, you need to pip3 install pyobjc-core and pyobjc.

To solve the symbol installation: Based on the research I've done, the module you're looking for might be called `symbol-release` as opposed to just symbol.

Comment: yes i all ready got pyobjc-core and pyobjc. and symbol-release worked tysm.

Comment: it seams when i install socketio breaks again

Comment: Is socketio broken, or does installing socketio break the script?